# Using Letter N in WHERE Cluase

Tags: sql, t-sql

I found something weird in this query

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE t1.country = N'USA';
```

why N Letter is used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The N stands for "National Character" and it means that the content of the string is [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

You should be using Unicode (`nchar/nvarchar`) whenever you might come across proper names or other entities that can contain characters outside of the default ASCII character set. If you don't surround such strings with the `N` prefix, you will lose data. For example:

```
SELECT N'ук ферт хер', 'ук ферт хер';
```

Results:

`-----------        -----------
ук ферт хер        ?? ???? ???`

You should also be sure to use the N prefix in your WHERE or other clauses against n(var)char columns. When you don't use the N prefix, you could suffer serious performance issues due to implicit conversion.

Comment: that means I should use N letter to evaluate any (nchar/nvarchar) columns either the string is Unicode or ASCII?

Comment: yes you are right @Nawaf

Answer (score 1):

N is for the compatibility of a character. Used for representing unicode characters.

Comment: You may want to look a bit longer at your answer and give something a little more succinct.

Comment: oh. sorry, my bad.. that was just my general idea. I'll do better next time captain!

Answer (score 1):

It declares the string as nvarchar data type, instead of varchar, and the difference is that varchar column only stores an 8-bit codepage and a nvarchar column can store any Unicode data